# GWT Lagging or Slow when rendering textbox

Tags: performance, debugging, gwt

Im experiencing some lag when I create a Web Application Starter Project when it renders the text box. Anyone know why and how to fix this? Its just the standard test code that comes with eclipse and is provided as a checkbox.

The video is here: http://videobin.org/+5hk/5x8.html

Comment: Try using firefox when using hosted mode. The Chrome dev plugin is known to be slow.

Comment: Can you provide source code or the link to the page where this can be downloaded? Did you try to compile the project and run off the javascript to see if there were any difference? Thanks

Comment: @DTing Thanks I didn't consider not using hosted mode vs Run as Web application from within eclipse would make much of a difference, Ill defiantly give it a try in hosted mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is lagging because you are using [development mode](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html). Compile your app, than remove gwt.codsrv parameter from address.